# Find root ng-class element

Tags: angularjs

I have a app in which I have a state called `suggestions`. When I click the button that transists from the current state to the `suggestions` state I want to add a css class to elements in the `application.html.haml` file (the root).

So the structure looks like this,

- application.html.haml

  - {"ui-view" => "frontpage"}

    - %a{"ui-sref" => ".suggestions", "ng-click" => "blur()"}

So the application has a div element with the `view` attribute, it loads the frontpage template in this view and in this template is a button that calls the `suggestions`state.

So when this button is clicked I want to add a class to a elemen in the `application.html.haml` but I can't get it to work.

In my suggestions controller I have,

```
$scope.contentBlur = function(){
  $scope.blur = 'blur';
}
```

In the `application.html.haml` I have

```
%body{"ng-class" => "blur"}
```

But when I click the link, the body does not change. However I put the `{"ng-class" => "blur"}` inside the template that loads when the `suggestions` state is entered it does work.

So it's probably because the `%body` element isn't connected to the suggestions controller (because the suggestions template is, and then it works).

So a solution might be to add the suggestions controller to the body element, but that seems a bit dirty. I hope there's a way I can find the `"ng-class"` element outside the controller somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Always nice to find the answer to your question after you've done 15 minutes of research.

By changing the `"ng-class"` to this it's working,

```
{"ng-class" => "{ 'blur': $root.blur=='blur' }"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), if you want to assign a class to your body element based on the current state, consider using [$state.includes](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_includes) method.

Example (in HTML):

```
<body ng-controller="BodyController as body" ng-class="{blur: body.state.includes('suggestions')">
```

...and in your `BodyController`:

```
angular.module('myApp)
  .controller('BodyController', BodyController);

function BodyController($state) {
  var body = this;
  this.state = $state;
}
```

The `$state.includes` method will detect if you are in a child state of `suggestions` as well, which may be useful. If that's not desired, use [$state.is](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_is) instead.